# How do I use CSS to select the first instance of a specific class?

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

I have a class that appears multiple times in a page, each time in it's own separate div. I want to select only the first instance of this class.

Example:

*The code I had here originally did not illustrate my situation well. I've updated the below to better reflect my actual code.*

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row project-header">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1><a href="index.html">Heading</a></h1>
            <h2>Subheader</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container sticky-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 line">
                <div>
                    First line
                    <p class="subtitle">Sample Subline</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container sticky-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 line">
                <div>
                    Second line
                    <p class="subtitle">Sample Subline</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I tried using **.line:first-child**, **.line:first-of-type**, and **.line:nth-of-type(1)** but came to understand that each instance of **.line** will be selected since they are always the first child of the parent of **.line**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the first class in one of the  containers. you can use the **:first-child** for that specific container and **.line** after that like this: `.container:first-child .line`

**Example:**

```css
.container:first-child .line {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    First Line
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    Second Line
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different classes to avoid confusion amongst the code, or use a bit of javascript to do the same thing.

If you use the following:

```
document.querySelector(".container") 
document.querySelector(".line")
```

Since multiple items will satisfy this requirement, then it will access only the first occurrence of either of the two classes. Then you can use a variety of methods to obtain the change you want in those two classes.